# Unity3d Prevent velocity from being added by a fixed joint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am currently working on a Unity3d project that makes use of fixed joints. When connecting two GameObjects using a fixed joint, I noticed a behavior that I couldn't explain. The gameobject that becomes part of a fixed joint gets velocity added for a short time. The added velocity disappears after a fraction of a second.

[image]

I add the fixed joint as follows:

```
baseObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = targetObject.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Is there an explanation for this behavior and is it possible to prevent it?